# Windows 10 creators Update affect my programs and data?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1709

I'm installing creators update to my office PC through the update assistant. Will it delete my data or affect any programs(Remove Softwares installed) ?

Comment: It will only delete your data if you select that option

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not delete any of your existing data nor should* it uninstall any of your programs.

It should be functionally identical to having updated your machine through Windows Update. I have updated a machine running an older version of Windows using the Update Assistant and aside from the update there were no unexpected programs or files missing. YMMV.

If you do encounter problems then, like the "normal" update, you should be able to revert to your previous installation.

---

*I say "should" because there may be some applications that have been specifically flagged as being incompatible with Windows 10 and are removed as part of the update process. You should get a notification if this happened when you log in after the update. The only thing I have seen this for personally is some audio "enhancement" package that I never used but was installed by my OEM.

Comment: But fresh install is a good option if you have a separate partition to store data and programs. I like the asterisk condition, that's true.